# How to create template to match based upon an XSLT parameter

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to create a standard-use XSLT that will perform a given task based upon a user-provided XPATH expression as an XSLT parameter.

That is, I need something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="$paramContainingXPATH">
  <!-- perform the task on the node(s) in the given xpath -->
</xsl:template>
```

For example, suppose I have some XML:

```
<xml>
  <nodeA>whatever</nodeA>
  <nodeB>whatever</nodeB>
  <nodeC>whatever</nodeC>
  <nodeD>whatever</nodeD>
  <nodeE>whatever</nodeE>
</xml>
```

The XSLT needs to transform just a node or nodes matching a provided XPATH expression.  So, if the xslt parameter is "/xml/nodeC", it processes nodeC.  If the xslt parameter is "*[local-name() = 'nodeC' or local-name() = 'nodeE']", it processes nodeC and nodeE.

This should work for absolutely *any* XML message.  That is, the XSLT cannot have any direct knowledge of the content of the XML.  So, it could be a raw XML, or a SOAP Envelope.

I was guessing I might need to grab all the nodes matching the xpath, and then looping over them calling a named template, and using the standard identity template for all other nodes.

All advice is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen.  I was hoping I could pull it off with the EXSLT dyn:evaluate, but I can't put that in a template match expression.  I am stuck on XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use? I would first check whether it has an option to treat a parameter as an XPath expression.

Comment: An example would be useful, IMHO.

Comment: Example provided in edit to original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match a template using a parameter - but you *can* traverse the tree and compare the path of each node with the given path. Here's a simple example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="path" select="'/world/America/USA/California'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="path-to-me">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::node()">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:if test="$path=$path-to-me">
        <xsl:call-template name="action"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="action">
    <return>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </return>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a slightly more ambitious **test input** of:

```
<world>
    <Europe>
        <Germany>1</Germany>
        <France>2</France>
        <Italy>3</Italy>
    </Europe>
    <America>
        <USA>
            <NewYork>4</NewYork>
            <California>5</California>
        </USA>
        <Canada>6</Canada>
    </America>
</world>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <return>5</return>
</root>
```

This could be made more efficient by passing the accumulated path as a parameter of the recursive template, so that each node needs only to add its own name to the chain.

**Note**:

1. The given path must be absolute;
2. Predicates (including positional predicates) and attributes are not implemented in this. They probably could be, with a bit more effort;
3. Namespaces are ignored (I don't see how you could pass an XPath as a parameter and include namespaces anyway).

If your processor supports an evaluate() extension function, you could forgo the calculated text path and test for intersection instead.

---

### Edit:

Here's an example using EXSLT dyn:evaluate() and set:intersection():

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="dyn set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="path" select="'/world/America/USA/California'"/>
<xsl:variable name="path-set" select="dyn:evaluate($path)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="set:intersection(. , $path-set)">
        <xsl:call-template name="action"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="action">
    <return>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </return>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this will also work with with paths like:

`/world/America/USA/*[2]`

`//California`

and many others that the text comparison method could not accommodate.

Comment: Nice.  I can't envision being able to handle namespaces this way either.  I'm not sure, though, not having namespaces would be too treacherous.  I suspect using local-name() to construct the path would work.  I hate that the given path must be absolute, though, as an XPATH such as "//nodename" would not work.  Yes, I do have EXSLT evaluate().  How would you test for intersection?

Comment: @JMorgan If you can use evaluate(), then a lot of things that cannot work with this method will start working, incl. `"//nodename"` (which *is* an absolute path). But if the path is not absolute, then the stylesheet wouldn't know from which context to evaluate it. I believe the ONLY solution for this would be to generate a new stylesheet, as suggested by Martin Honnen.

Comment: Thank you.  It is working with the intersection and dynamic evaluate.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need that feature with XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 then I think you should consider writing one stylesheet that takes that string parameter with the XPath expression and then simply generates the code of a second stylesheet where the XPath expression is used as a match pattern and the other needed templates like the identity template are included statically. Dynamic XPath evaluation is only available in XSLT 3.0 or in earlier versions as a proprietary extension mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending the element name as a param to the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:param name="user"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="generic" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="generic">
        <count><xsl:value-of select="count(.//*[local-name()=$user])"/></count>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope this could help!

Comment: Not quite what I'm trying.  I need the template match expression to match that of a full xpath expression.  I can certainly grab nodes based upon the xpath expression, but I need to perform an identity transform on all nodes NOT matching the user provided XPATH expression, and then transform all nodes matching the user provided XPATH expression with a template.